# How to generate a valid netplan configuration file?

Tags: yaml-cpp

Has anyone created a config file for netplan? I'm having compatibility issues with the generated file. For example, these are indentation and notation in the routes node: -to , via.

Can anyone give me an example of creating such a file or tips on how to do it?